# Can the Tor Project prove that they haven't been served with FISA warrants? If so, how?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

I understand that asking directly if they've been served with FISA warrants would get a 'No' since these warrants come with a gag order. So:

Can the Tor Project (or anyone) prove that they haven't been served with FISA warrants? If so, how?

And if they've been served - what info can you provide on them (scope, when, etc)?

Comment: i'm not sure, but perhaps a [warrant canary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warrant_canary)...?

Comment: DJCrashdummy - thanks for the reply. I read thru the content of that wikipedia page and it says "In September 2014, U.S. security researcher Moxie Marlinspike wrote that "every lawyer I've spoken to has indicated that having a 'canary' you remove or choose not to update would likely have the same legal consequences as simply posting something that explicitly says you've received something."

Comment: Anyone know if the TOR project has used a warrant canary? I met them last year at DefCon but did not think of asking the question. Was planning on asking them this year but it looks like DC is cancelled this year.